# Core Data fault on frequent data updating?

Tags: core-data, updates, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, magicalrecord

I use operations in operation queue which update data and send notifications at the end.

My problem is I may process the old data while a new entities are already available and this causes an exception. I could process the old data and then process the new ones but I must to store/copy old data anyways.

How to solve this issue if Core Data doesn't allow to retain/copy its managed objects? I tried `MagicalRecord` but both it and pure Core Data don't provide the ready necessary solutions.

Comment: I used parentContext to create a temporary Entity object to store the old data, then let the new entries in. Without saving the parentContext, the old data will not go into the context and occur conflict. I delete that old data object later on. Not sure this way is good for you though.

Comment: could you place an example

Comment: I tried to find some examples from my old projects but yet nothing. You can look into this SO thread and see the second answer using parentContext.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166592/create-an-nsmanagedobject-without-saving

Comment: Or this one using no context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256195/how-to-deal-with-temporary-nsmanagedobject-instances